# React Native - Where to store non-serializable-object globally

Tags: reactjs, react-native

It's a React Native project.

***Requirement***:

- I need to initialize 3rd party client once
- The client object is non-serialzable
- I need to access the object in different components

It's like a global variable, just it cannot store in redux(As redux suggest only store plain object).

Anyone can advice where else I should store the object and access globally.

Answer (score 1):

You can store globally accessible variables on the `window` object.

The following is from the Create React App documentation:

> **[Using Global Variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-global-variables/)**
>
> When you include a script in the HTML file that defines global
>   variables and try to use one of these variables in the code, the
>   linter will complain because it cannot see the definition of the
>   variable.
>
> You can avoid this by reading the global variable explicitly from the
>   `window` object, for example:
>
> `const $ = window.$;`
>
> This makes it clear you are using a global
>   variable intentionally rather than because of a typo.
>
> Alternatively, you can force the linter to ignore any line by adding
>   `// eslint-disable-line` after it.